# HTML/CSS - How to position my image to the right so that it can be aligned with my text on the left?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am new to HTML and CSS, some problems have come up when I tried to write the code. What I want is that

- Text (on the left middle part) and image (on the right middle part) are side by side
- Responsive design - so that text is on the top and image is at the bottom

Here are the questions,

1. How to position my image to the right so that it can be aligned with my text on the left?
2. Both text and image seems to have skewed downward.
3. When I resize my browser, the texts and images are not responsive and everything is falling apart, how can I fix that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```css
.first_section {
    background-image:url('http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/zinc-white_zpsiibjtmdi.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 200px 150px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
}

#first_section_text {
    float: left;
    text-align: left; /*Set everything to the left */
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

#first_section_image {
    float: right;   /* float property can be used to wrap text around images */  
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
        <div class="first_section">

            <div id="first_section_text">
                <p>IT'S OFFICIALLY SANDWICHES SEASON</p>
                <p>This summer, we've got more sandwiches options than ever. From the new mexican style to our classic chicken and beef sandwich, there's a style to fill you up on any hot day.</p>
                <a href="navigation_bar/sub_menu/sandwiches.html">Explore now!</a>
            </div>

            <div id="first_section_image">
                <img src="http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/Sandwiches_zps99hlhkod.jpg" height= "235" width= "235"/>
            </div>           

        </div>
```

Comment: use media queries of CSS

Comment: Media queries can be good only if written properly. Instead of media queries I would suggest look into bootstrap. You just need to add the class and it's done.

Have a look here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @AkashAgrawal. Yes you are right. Bootstrap does all the work with simple classes. col-md, col-sm, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see snippet below or fiddle here > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb1v1nae/3/)**

first. that padding on the `.first_section` is a mistake. that's why your content is positioned so down, as you put it : `Both text and image seems to have skewed downward.`

second. use `float:left;` and `width` on `.first_section` so it will inherit the height from it's content.

i used `width:90%` with `margin:0 5%` because i saw you wanted to have margins left and right.

then to position the text above and the image under the text, when the screen gets smaller, use `media queries`. i used a `media query` for screen size smaller than `640px` . but it's just an example, change it however you want.

in that media query add `width:100%` to both text and image so they will stay one after the other.

let me know if it helps

```css
.first_section {
    background-image:url('http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/zinc-white_zpsiibjtmdi.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    background-size: cover;
    float:left;
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    padding:15px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
}

#first_section_text {
    float: left;
    text-align: left; /*Set everything to the left */
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

#first_section_image {
    float: right;   /* float property can be used to wrap text around images */  
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 #first_section_image  { float:left;width:100%;}
 #first_section_text{ float:left;width:100%;}

}
```

```html
<div class="first_section">

            <div id="first_section_text">
                <p>IT'S OFFICIALLY SANDWICHES SEASON</p>
                <p>This summer, we've got more sandwiches options than ever. From the new mexican style to our classic chicken and beef sandwich, there's a style to fill you up on any hot day.</p>
                <a href="navigation_bar/sub_menu/sandwiches.html">Explore now!</a>
            </div>

            <div id="first_section_image">
                <img src="http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/Sandwiches_zps99hlhkod.jpg" height= "235" width= "235"/>
            </div>           

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.first_section {
    background-image:url('http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/zinc-white_zpsiibjtmdi.jpg');
    background-position:center top;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 200px 150px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
}

#first_section_text {
    float: left;
    text-align: left; /*Set everything to the left */
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
}

#first_section_image {
    float: right;   /* float property can be used to wrap text around images */  
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  
#first_section_text
  , #first_section_image{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first_section">

            <div id="first_section_text">
                <p>IT'S OFFICIALLY SANDWICHES SEASON</p>
                <p>This summer, we've got more sandwiches options than ever. From the new mexican style to our classic chicken and beef sandwich, there's a style to fill you up on any hot day.</p>
                <a href="navigation_bar/sub_menu/sandwiches.html">Explore now!</a>
            </div>

            <div id="first_section_image">
                <img src="http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/Sandwiches_zps99hlhkod.jpg" height= "235" width= "235"/>
            </div>           

        </div>
```

Comment: There can be 2 easy ways. 1. Adding bootstrap css. 2. Writing media queries as above

Answer (score 0):

please check below code.
I've used your markup and css, just modified it.
Your target is show image first and then text in mobile view, so to manage, i've added image first and then text in markup, then added floats to them in css.
In mobile view, removed float, so that image will display 1st and then textual content.
Try this solution :)

```css
.first_section {
  background-image:url('http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/zinc-white_zpsiibjtmdi.jpg');
  background-position:center top;
  background-size: cover;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding:100px 20px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
}

#first_section_text {
  float: left;
  text-align: left; /*Set everything to the left */
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

#first_section_image {
  float: right;   /* float property can be used to wrap text around images */  
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width:480px){
  #first_section_image{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }
  #first_section_text{
    float:none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="first_section">
  <div id="first_section_image">
    <img src="http://i347.photobucket.com/albums/p462/jimprince1990/Sandwiches_zps99hlhkod.jpg" height= "235" width= "235"/>
  </div>           
  <div id="first_section_text">
    <p>IT'S OFFICIALLY SANDWICHES SEASON</p>
    <p>This summer, we've got more sandwiches options than ever. From the new mexican style to our classic chicken and beef sandwich, there's a style to fill you up on any hot day.</p>
    <a href="navigation_bar/sub_menu/sandwiches.html">Explore now!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```